# Jib Maven Plugin: How to always pull base image before image build?

Tags: jib, maven-jib

I'm using the [Jib Maven plugin](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin) to build a container image, and have the following issue: sometimes the locally available base image (e.g. `foo/bar/base/parent-image:latest`) becomes older than the one available in the remote repository.

Invoking manually `docker pull parent-image:latest` pulls the most current `:latest` version, but I'd like this to happen automatically every time my image is built, similarly to the `--pull` parameter of [Docker CLI](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options): `docker build --pull my-image:latest`.

Can this (always pulling the  base image before image build) be obtained with current version (3.2.1) of [Jib Maven plugin](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin)?

I tried prefixing the base image with `registry://` like described in ["Setting the base image"](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin#setting-the-base-image), and it makes no difference:

```
      <from>
        <image>registry://foo/bar/base/parent-image:latest</image>
      </from>
```

I could try to set the base image cache directory, described in ["System Properties"](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin#system-properties), to a random temp directory, but I don't want such a overkill workaround.

Comment: Seems to be the default behaviour with 3.3.2, far as I can tell.

Comment: @Raphael Thanks for the hint. Currently I'm using 3.3.1 and haven't upgraded to 3.3.2. because the changelog didn't seem to mention relevant changes. I'll reinvestigate later this week.

Comment: I guess that would be a breaking change, so a patch bump shouldn't change things.  Maybe I misinterpreted the behaviour I saw; seemed to _me_ it always tried to pull unless I used `docker://..` in `<from>`. (Which I didn't want because the image I used only existed locally, not on any registry.)